# Can't connect with Google

Tags: google, online-accounts

I am running 23.04 - all updates current.

When I got to connect my online account with Google, I type in my email address, but then when it gives me the password prompt, I am not able to type anything there.

Connecting with Microsoft works fine, but connecting with Google isn't possible.

This is within the settings area of Ubuntu. Settings > Online Accounts > Google.

Comment: Which software does not allow you to enter your password? Is it a browser? If yes, which one?

Comment: This is within the settings area of Ubuntu. 

Settings > Online Accounts > Google.